# How keys is predefined in ModelState & how to add more keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

During debugging, i found that my ModelState contain 7 keys. I want to know how it is defined, where can I add/delete the keys and how to do it. Thanks.

[image of my ModelState keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q66Pa.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could easily find this using google. https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/

Answer (score 0):

The keys are the property names, if you want to add your own errors then you simply use:
`ModelState.AddModelError("key", "errorMsg");`

If you want to add an error to an existing key, use: `ModelState["key"].Errors.Add("errorMsg");`